# DB2 Hibernate paging on an SQL query

Tags: hibernate, db2, paging

We are using hibernate with DB2.  Our method needs to page to support a front-end.  We use the `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult` methods.  This works with HQL, but when we try to turn the SQL into a bean via:

```
sql.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SubscriptionAndDecode.class));
```

We get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for ROWNUMBER_ on class gov.usdoj.afms.enote.model.query.UM02.SubscriptionAndDecode
```

Which is true, in that this bean does not have `ROWNUMBER_` since it was not an element of the SQL.  I have read elsewhere that Hibernate should be building a sub-query to create a fake rownumber and do the pagination since DB2 doesn't provide it much help, but this `ROWNUMBER_` shouldn't be part of the actual result nor part of the transformed bean as i understand it.

Of course we could add a "fake" property to every bean that is used this way, but that's not optimal.  Is there something we need to do to massage the bean transformation or whatever?